# any third party .net sdk for programming against any mail server

Tags: c#, service, sdk

I want a c# windows service that will fetch all incoming emails (and their attachments), and I can do whatever I want with the emails, eg. I can store them in a folder on my desktop etc.

I believe what I need is a sdk which I will reference in my .net application. Provide all the connection strings within the objects of the sdk and any other necessary info to connect to the ANY mail server. Then I can fetch the incoming emails and manipulate them to my requirements.

The thing that is important for me is that; the window service should be completely independent of the location of the mail server. It should be independant of any type of mail server; ie: the mail server could be exhange or any thing else.

Can any one tell me please, what third party sdks are available to perform this functionality.

And is there any thing else that is needed to perform the above task.

Thank you and much obliged.

Comment: Why would you need a 3rd party..? you should be able to do that using the System.Mail Class unless I am not understanding what you want to accomplish.. also what mail do you use..? are you using MS Outlook or Exchange Server or anything like that..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE - System.Net.Mail only supports SMTP and POP. I believe the OP is looking for something that works with IMAP as well (using the same abstraction).

Comment: thanks aniatholine for the comment it's hard to tell sometimes what individuals want when asking questions because of the depth of abstraction that they go into.. I think that your link to AENetMail mail should help in getting him started..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MailSystem.NET](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) (more complete) and [AENetMail](https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail) (only IMAP but good implementation) look like libraries you can use. I don't know if the level of abstraction of these libraries is quite what you need - but then again, these are open-source so you can probably contribute any enhancements you make.

Comment: Thank you every one ... God bless you all